# migrating to ros: duplicate package names

Tags: ros, stack, package, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to migrate our robotics team's existing software, which uses a custom qmake-based build system, to ROS, but I'm running into a problem where packages have the same name, but are in different stacks. For Instance, we have unrelated code in:

```
RobotA/Sensors/Vision
RobotB/Sensors/Vision
```

I've tried making RobotA and RobotB stacks, but then `rospack find Vision` only sees `RobotB/Sensors/Vision`. Is there a way to make the ROS build system and bash tools look inside a specific stack, or directory? I'd rather not have to redesign the entire repository. It makes sense that this would be possible... what if you wanted to integrate somebody else's stack, but they used a name that you also used?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10304/migrating-to-ros:-duplicate-package-names/) by [btown](https://answers.ros.org/users/709/btown/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-06-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure, if that achieves what you want, but you can adjust your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.
If you include either RobotA or RobotB, the ros tools will only find the vision package in that stack.

Using both at the same time under the same name is not possible.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [btown](https://answers.ros.org/users/709/btown/) on 2011-06-18**:
Thanks! I was afraid of that, but I'll just make a script that changes the package path.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS stack and package names are global to the entire ROS universe.

It will be much less confusing and annoying to give all your stacks and packages unique names, like `robot_a_vision` and `robot_b_vision` ([lower case names are preferred](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Naming#Packages)).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-06-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3